# File created using Python is written to wrong directory

Tags: python, linux

I'm trying to create a script that will create a new file within one of my sub-directories. (A sub-directory of which my .py script isn't located)

This following bit of code works, however when I run it, the file is created in the directory of which I'm in. (Directory: project) But I want it to be created in "Directory: results".

```py
import time
import glob, os

timestr = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S_Output")#variable that creates file name

filepath = os.path.join('/home/project/results' )

f = open(timestr, "w+")
```

EDIT: I've also tried the following:

```
filepath = os.path.join('/home/project/results', timestr )

f = open(filepath, "w+")
```

But I only get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lab06.py", line 6, in <module>
    f = open(filepath, "w+")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/project/results/2019-08-16_04:00:30_Output'
```

Any Idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing you want `filepath + timestr`.

Comment: `timestr = os.path.join('/home/project/results', timestr)` maybe?

Comment: I think that it is because you forgot a `/` at the end. So try `/home/project/results/`. What about that?

Comment: @zixuan Unfortunately that's not it.. This has been going on for hours.. I don't know why it's doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are opening the `timestr` file, without appending the results path.  You should do

```
filepath = os.path.join('/home/project/results', timestr)

f = open(filepath, "w+")
```

---

If the directories do not exist, then this will create them:

```
dirpath = '/home/project/results'
os.makedirs(dirpath)
filepath = os.path.join(dirpath, timestr)

f = open(filepath, "w+")
```

If that still doesn't work, then there may be permissions issues you need to deal with.

Comment: I should probably have mentioned this in my original post - I've tried this, but then I get this error message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lab06.py", line 6, in <module>
    f = open(filepath, "w+")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/project/results/2019-08-16_04:00:30_Output'

Comment: Then edit your post to include this.

Comment: @zixuan Does the directory `/home/projects/results` exist?

Comment: Wait, what?  You're asking me? I'm not the asker of this.

Comment: @JonathonK Yes, it does

Comment: @zixuan Doh!  Apparently I shouldn't be on SO right now...

Comment: @Jannejannesson that's strange to me, I would have expected `/home/username/project/results`...

Comment: Jesus christ.. I've been at this since 02:00am, it's currently 04:30. I was at a desperate low point coming here.. Thanks for your sharp eye, sorry for wasting every bodies time... ._.

Comment: This answer is also correct @alexbclay For the next person who is here for the same reason I was.. check your filepath carefully..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have permission to create a file in that directory. You can check by creating a file in that directory manually.

Comment: Man I wish that was it, unfortunately I can create files in that directory

Answer (score 0):

Just do (assuming the path exists, if not, make it)

```
path = '/home/project/results/'

f = open(path+timestr,'w+')
```